# How to remove carriage return char after it's pressed?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have a textarea which is restricted to input only numbers. I want to remove carriage return char after user presses enter key. Here's my code:

```
// Change tempo
function changeTempo(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.charCode == 13) {
        // Some code here
    }
    // Remove enter char
    removeCarriageReturnsAndNewLines(tempo_txt.text);
}

function removeCarriageReturnsAndNewLines($myString:String):String {
    var newString:String;
    var findCarriageReturnRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp("\r", "gi");
    newString = $myString.replace(findCarriageReturnRegExp, "");
    var findNewLineRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp("\n", "gi");
    newString = newString.replace(findNewLineRegExp, "");
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Is this a multi line textfield? If you don't want anything that starts a new line, make it a single line textfield (multiline = false).

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's a text area, i don't want to use a textfield.

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 textarea component: disallow user to enter a line break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239891/as3-textarea-component-disallow-user-to-enter-a-line-break)

Comment: I see, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239891/as3-textarea-component-disallow-user-to-enter-a-line-break does this work for you?

Comment: it cant't detect enter key. I tried: *if (tempo_txt.text.charAt(tempo_txt.length) == "\r") {*

Comment: The TextArea dispatches a distinct Event when the Enter key is pressed, see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html#event:enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the easiest way is to listen to text input, something like this:

```
var t:TextArea = this.ta; //ta is on the timeline
t.restrict = "0-9"; //restricts the input only to numbers
t.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onTextInput, true); //use capture phase to be able to prevent the default behavior (text input)

function onTextInput(e:TextEvent):void {
    if(e.text.indexOf("\n") > -1) {
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default behavior of the field
    }
}
```

I cannot test this right now but I guess it should work without problems.